# What does a Microsoft Safelink contain?

Tags: email, microsoft

Regarding the URL query arguments of a Safelink:

- Why do they contain my e-mail address (the recipient)?
- What are these two longish strings? Look like IDs of a database. Does Microsoft store Safelinks in a database?
- Some coworker reported that Safelinks expire. Is this true? If yes, how is this expiration date determined (database, or is it encoded in these longish strings)?

Comment: This looks like a question for Microsoft. But why the email ID? To tie the clicking of the external link to the user. Do they store the link in a database? Of course ...

Comment: IIRC, MS Safelinks embed the entire URL. If the rest expires, they could still theoretically let the link connect after a click-time blocklist query. They'd lose only the click-tracking component, but if it's old, they probably don't care about that.